# Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am working on swift project and calling webservice with Alamofire.
But, while calling post method, I am getting following error.

```
Header file :

let accessTokenHeaderFile = [
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type" :"application/json",
    "X-TOKEN" : UtilityClass.sharedInstance.accessTokenString
]

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params as? [String:Any], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: accessTokenHeaderFile).responseJSON { response in
          requestVC.removeLoader()
            switch (response.result) {
            case .success:
                if response.result.value != nil{
                    completionHandler (response.result.value)
                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                failureHandler (error as NSError?)
                break
            }
        }
```

And the error is

```
FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
```

Can anyone suggest me, how to fix this, I tried googling, but whatever I found the answers not helped me.

Comment: It seems that the response is not a Valid JSON. Could you try to get the responseString instead of responseJSON and check its JSON validity?

Comment: I am very new to swift, can you please guide me how to change from responseJSON to responseString?

Comment: Can you just try to print the returned value and check if the JSON syntax is correct or not?

Answer (score 3):

**Error of 3840 saying that the response from server is not a valid JSON string.** So you can check you **parameters key value** may be it’s wrong assign because **similar of responseString instead of responseJSON**.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I assign/executing this?

Comment: are you matching your response dictionary key and api key is similar or not?

Comment: Please do your response dictionary key same as a api key. the Error automatically solve.

Answer (score 1):

Your response is not a valid json hence you're getting this error. Please check the `response.response?.statusCode` to see what is server returning. And if you want to see the actual response try using `responseString` or `responseData` methods instead of `responseJSON`

e.g.

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params as? [String:Any], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: accessTokenHeaderFile). responseData {
```

You can find out more [response methods here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-handling)

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'Foundation._NSSwiftData' (0x1114f1990) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10bdde2d8).
getting this error

Comment: and while printing the error code, (lldb) po response.response?.statusCode
▿ Optional<Int>
  - some : 404

Comment: You need to convert data into the json dictionary, you can cast it directly