# the output of webservice is not giving the required json in swift using alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, web-services, alamofire

1)

I am new in using alamofire.Here is my attempt to use alamofire to make web service check where i am wrong .I Have made a login webservice in the loginviewcontroller.swift as follows

```
let url="http://192.169.201.32:9000//users/authenticate"

        @IBAction func DoLogin(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:["username":"andrews","password":"admin2"], encoding: URLEncoding.default)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    print("abcsign in")
                    print(response)
                    print("abcsign in3")
                    print(response.result)
                    //to get status code
                    if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                        switch(status){
                        case 201:
                            print("example success")
                        default:
                            print("error with response status: \(status)")
                        }
                    }
                    //to get JSON return value
                    if let result = response.result.value {
                        let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                        print("abcsign in 2")
                        print(JSON)

                    }

            }

            if(login_button.titleLabel?.text == "Logout")
            {
                let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                preferences.removeObject(forKey: "session")

                LoginToDo()
            }
            else{
                login_now(username:username_input.text!, password: password_input.text!)
            }

        }
```

print(response)

> FAILURE
>
> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailu>reReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 2.}))

print(response.result)

> FAILURE
>
> ```
> error with response status: 404
> ```

2)

The second signUpviewcontroller.swift is connected with the signUp view controller .In signUpViewController.swift the code for singUp webservice is as follow

```
  let url="http://192.169.201.32:9000//patient/signUp"

    @IBAction func signUpButtonWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:["dob":DateOfBirthTextFeild.text ,
                                                          "email":emailIdTextField.text ,
                                                          "firstName":FirstNameTextField.text ,
                                                          "gender":genderTextField.text ,
                                                          "lastName":LastNameTextField.text ,
                                                          "middleName":MiddleNameTextField.text ,
                                                          "password":passwordTextField.text ,    //password must be 8 char long
            "ssn":ssnTextField.text], encoding: URLEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("abcsig up ")
                print(response)
                print("abcsign up 3")
                print(response.result)
                //to get status code
                if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch(status){
                    case 201:
                        print("example success")
                    default:
                        print("error with response status: \(status)")
                    }
                }
                //to get JSON return value
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                    print("abcsign up in 2")
                    print(JSON)

                }

        }
    }
```

print(response)

> FAILURE
>
> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailu>reReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 2.}))

print(response.result)

> error with response status: 404

how can I get the valid json response ?

you can download the project from this links https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q__ydaQ7o0fKcFHdq6ymkxh52IEf7hMK/view?usp=sharing
Here on postman the api is showing the required json out put .

**Sigin Up:**

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNF2C.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCnDM.png)

**Login:**

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rowZ.png)

[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIDWP.png)

provide the parameters in body. You can add the json parameters converting the json url request to post .In below tab select body put the parameters here by selecting the raw.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970997/alamofire-aferror-responseserializationfailurereason-jsonserializationfailederr?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Use `JSONEncoding` and do not use `//`, just single `/` is required in request url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshots you shared, I found that there are 2 issue in the API calling.

**1) Change encoding from `URLEncoding` to `JSONEncoding`**

**2) Update your url by avoiding double `//` in the request**

---

Perform the following changes:

```
    Alamofire.request(url,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters:["username":"andrews","password":"admin2"],
                      encoding: URLEncoding.default)
```

**To:**

```
    Alamofire.request(url,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters:["username":"andrews","password":"admin2"],
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

---

```
    let parameters = ["dob":"16-08-2017",
                      "email":"ali45324@heurixtics.com",
                      "firstName":"abdul",
                      "gender":"male",
                      "lastName":"hasmi",
                      "middleName":"rauf",
                      "password":"12345678",
                      "ssn":"1235"]
    Alamofire.request(url,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters:parameters,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

***Also you need to correct your request urls:***

```
let url = "http://192.169.201.32:9000//users/authenticate"
let url = "http://192.169.201.32:9000//patient/signUp"
```

**To:**

```
let url = "http://192.169.201.32:9000/users/authenticate"
let url = "http://192.169.201.32:9000/patient/signUp"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this link **"http://192.169.201.32:9000/users/authenticate"**

I think you have an extra /

404 Not Found means that the issue is on the link 
It's a page not found error